# Project open with form automatically vb6

Tags: vb6

When you open a project in vb6, put to open a form automatically. How do I remove this form. Remove this opening automatically. The project now opens with the form open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along side your project's `.vbp` file, there should be a `.vbw` file with the same name. Edit this file in notepad, clearing it's contents. Save it, and then mark the `.vbw` file as read-only.

From [here](http://cislab.moorparkcollege.edu/gcampbell/ProjFiles-vb6.htm):

> Windows Layout (.vbw) file. Only found in Visual Basic version 5 and
>   higher. This file is created whenever you close a visual basic Project
>   (whether you modify it or not). It stores information about the
>   positions of open windows in the Visual Basic development environment.
>   This file is not an important part of a project, and does not need to
>   be included with the above project files when backing them up to a
>   floppy disk or another computer.